# SQL Query. Give all pids with sys_language_uid =1 and no sys_language_uid = 2

Tags: sql, typo3

Im practicing with TYPO3 and I want to build a query for translations.

I need all pids which have the `sys_language_uid=1` but not the translation `sys_language_uid=2`

How can I build it with SQL?

```
SELECT pids FROM pages_language_overlay 
WHERE sys_language_uid=1 
AND (where sys_language_uid=2 doesnt exist)
```

THX

Answer (score 1):

One option here is to use aggregation:

```
SELECT pids
FROM pages_language_overlay
GROUP BY pids
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN sys_language_uid = 1 THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
    COUNT(CASE WHEN sys_language_uid = 2 THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another is to use not exists

(usually fastest)

```
SELECT pids 
FROM pages_language_overlay PLO 
WHERE sys_language_uid = 1 
  and not exists (SELECT 1 
                  FROM pages_language_overlay PLO2
                  WHERE PLO2.sys_language_uid = 2 
                    and PLO.pids = PLO2.pids)
```

assuming PIDS is a PK.

Or using a left join... when no pids match is found on uid 2 
Not the fasted but offers more options on data.

```
SELECT PLO.pids 
FROM pages_language_overlay PLO 
LEFT JOIN pages_language_overlay PLO2
  on PLO.PIDS = PLO2.PIDS
 and PLO2.sys_language_uid = 2
WHERE sys_language_uid = 1 
 and PLO2.PIDS is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option to left-join but require null

```
select
      PLO.pids
   from
      pages_language_overlay PLO
         LEFT JOIN pages_language_overlay PLO2
            on PLO.pids = PLO2.pids
            AND PLO2.sys_language_uid = 2
   where
          PLO.sys_language_uid = 1
      AND PLO2.sys_language_uid IS NULL
```